# Scroll to table row or list item in an Angular app

Tags: html, angular, typescript, scroll

In the code snapshot below in `app.component.html`, I display clickable rows in a table in Lines 39 to 58. Once the user clicks a row, I display other relevant rows in a table named `suraTable` as shown in Lines 63 to 77. Namely, when the user clicks on a row, the function `onSelectAya(aya, suraTable)` in `app.component.ts` is called. That function loads the necessary rows and the table is displayed.

What I am stuck with is this. Suppose `suraTable` ends up with 100 rows. The current behaviour is that rows 1, 2, 3... are displayed of course. I need to be able to show the table at Row 50 say (information carried in the parameter `aya` on Line 91). How do I scroll to that position? I tried the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) way but when checking the values before and after the setting of `suraTable.scrollTop`, the value is always 0 (0 pixels that is). Line 100 shows that when `console.log(suraTable)` is reached, expected output is generated in the browser, which means that I am getting hold of the element correctly to start with.

So, how do I scroll to a specific row in a table, or to an item in a list (I could convert the whole structure to a list if easier) from within the `app.component.ts` component? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not work on old browsers.

If this is simply a scrolling thing, you could add specific id to your rows so you can know theyr number, and then do

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("rowNumber"+rowNumber);
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

If when the scrolling is taking part your element is not rendered on DOM, try adding a callback for when that rendering is finished. If that is not possible, maybe a `setTimeout` can do.

Comment: I see where this is going. I have added an id for each `tr`, and when I do a `console.log(suraTable)`, I do see the id for each `tr` (rn1, rn2, rn3...). However, when I do a console.log(document.getElementById('rn3')) for example, I am getting `null`!

Comment: Okay, got it to work using your idea. To get over the `null` issue, I implemented the check you pointed out in the last Angular lifecycle hook called `ngAfterViewChecked()`, which is rendered after the dust settles on the view components. If there are no other solutions (was hoping with observables maybe...), your method will be the "accepted" one shortly. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel. It's a nice solution and it's working perfect. Accepted :-).

Comment: How can i achieve using nativeElement reference?

Answer (score 5):

```
<mat-row id="{{task.taskId}}"
                *matRowDef='let task; columns: columnsReadyTask;let i = index;'></mat-row>
```

if working with datasources, you will need some delay after getting element on the page with id...

```
setTimeout(() => {
      const selectedRow = document.getElementById(taskId);
      if(selectedRow) {
        selectedRow.scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});
      }
    }, 500);
```